# Como agregar un listener y un bindBiderectional a un slider desde una ventana "APPLICATION_MODAL" en JavaFX

Tags: javafx, slider, listener

Estoy tratando de crear un controlador de volumen con un slider, pero este lo tengo en una ventana tipo "APPLICATION_MODAL" y no es capaz de pasarme los datos a la ventana root. Al cerrar la ventana modality me arroja un "NullPointerException" y no es capaz de mostrarme absolutamente nada desde su listener.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que uses un MediaView, mi sugerencia es que vuelvas la variable estatica para acceder a la misma desde cualquier clase

```
public static MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
```

Otra manera seria cuando crees la otra interfaz, guardar en una variable la referencia del root que seria el anchorPane que es el que contiene todos los elementos que componen la interfaz, y luego de alli, buscar el elmento de interes para que puedas acceder a el y modificar a voluntad.
Existe otra manera mas pero es mas elborada que podrias investigar. Pero pienso que estas serian una buena solucion.